# How to position div vertically using YUI grids?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, yui-grids

[alt text http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/2900/yuicssquestion.gif](http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/2900/yuicssquestion.gif)

Hi,

I am using YUI grids for layout design.
I want to position col3 vertically, and make it always stick to the bottom of the page. How to do that?

I cannot find any online documentation about vertical positioning in YUI grids. Hope someone can shed some light on this :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no yui-specific way of doing what you're asking, but you should be able to make col3 stick to the bottom by setting it to:

bottom: 0px;

Note that col2 will not automatically adjust its height to go all the way to where the start of col3 is. Heights in CSS work a lot different from the way widths do.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to center my ajax image loading status.

```
<div id="loader" class="yui3-g">
 <div class="yui3-u-1 ui-widget-overlay" style="z-index: 1100;">
    <img src="resources/images/ajax-loader.gif" 
    style="position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;margin-right: -50%;transform: 
           translate(-50%, -50%)"/>
 </div>
</div>
```